# removing redundancy when grouping two columns

Tags: mysql, select

Below is my table:

[image: Table structure]

I want to get the results based on values of `sender` and `Reciver` and group them in such a way that I don't have redundant results.

Example:

sender = 2
reciver = 1

reciver= 2 
sender=1

In the example above both results should not be shown, only one should result should be displayed..

I am using mysql and the code I am using is given below, which gives mutiple results as shown in the figure..

```
SELECT Mid,sender,Reciver 
FROM `tbl_messages`
WHERE sender=1 or Reciver = 1 
GROUP by Reciver,sender or sender,Reciver;
```

Comment: You didn't mention which one you wanted to keep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT newSender, newReceiver/*some aggregate functions or access other comlumns*/ FROM (
    SELECT Mid,/* add more columns if needed*/
           case when sender < reciver then sender else receiver end newSender,
           case when sender > reciver then sender else receiver end newReceiver
    FROM `tbl_messages`
    WHERE sender = 1 or Reciver = 1 
) a GROUP by newSender, newReceiver;
```

Comment: If you don't think mid is relevant to the problem, don't include it in the solution

Comment: @Strawberry It might be (and probably is) relevant to OP, that is why I included it i n my solution. But thanks for remark :)

Comment: mid was relevant and there were a few more columns which i needed to add, so i thought it would helpful to other users so i added a comment, but i suck at formatting thus the mess.. nevertheless really amazing and helpful.. wish my upvote would have made an impact, this deserves a million upvotes, i almost spend my whole morning trying a million stupid things.. thanks a lot @michalTurczyn really appreacitate it...

Comment: @AdarshaNepal Then you should accept the answer (green check mark to the left of the answer) :)